# PHP - Convert decimal into hours wherein exceeding 60 minutes will be added to hours

Tags: php

I have this decimal value:

```
$decimalVal = 1.92
```

Now I want to convert this into time (H:s) and another problem is that during conversion, exceeding 60 minutes must be added to hours and the remaining minutes will be left.

```
$decimalVal = 1.92
.. some code here ..

// desired output is 02:32 (2 hours, 32 minutes)
```

I've search everywhere but nothing seems to work.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: In which unit is this 1.92 in? We need to know that clearly before we convert this to H:s

Comment: Is $decimalVal guaranteed to have exact 2 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator, it's just a float value

Comment: @LYF_HKN yes, only 2 digits after decimal point which represents minutes

Comment: Is [this](http://ideone.com/GxWIml) what you want?

Comment: @LYF_HKN Thank you! That's what I've been searching for!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://ideone.com/GxWIml). Thanks to LYF_HKN!

Here's the code from the link:

```
function convert($value) {
  if ( !preg_match('/^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})$/', $value, $matches) ||
      count($matches) !== 3)
    return 'convert: Invalid value provided';

  $matches[1] += floor($matches[2] / 60);
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $matches[1], $matches[2] % 60);
}

$decimalVal = 1.92;
// desired output is 02:32 (2 hours, 32 minutes)
echo convert($decimalVal);
```